# How to use single.php output in function.php

Tags: loop

In `single.php`, inside the loop the code shows text output.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
echo wp_strip_all_tags($content);
$Temp_text=wp_strip_all_tags($content);

?>
```

Is there any way to use `$Temp_text` in `functions.php`.

Comment: you want to use the content of a post ? what do you want to do with it ?

Comment: I want to create the title, description , and keyword from this text and pass it to SEO. I am using YOAST SEO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undesrtand well what you want to do. You mean this??? (the last line):

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
echo wp_strip_all_tags($content);
$Temp_text=wp_strip_all_tags($content);

do_something($Temp_text);

?>
```

And implement `do_something()` inside `functions.php`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. In  single.php, shortcode is running. I am calling do-shortcode in function.php. As a result shortcode rendered two times: one for  calling it from function and other inside single.php. I want to use the text output in function.php. Yes the last line I want to implement.